# Slenium-Java: Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated()) always fails for negative scenarios

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, expected-condition

`ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated throws Timeout Exception` and terminates program.

**Step**

1. Launch browser and navigate to Loginpage.
2. Enter user name, password and click on SignIn
3. Since it is taking different times for loading I want to wait till the sign in button to be invisible

This is working fine for the positive cases where I'm using valid credentials and click on login. but it always fails for the negative case i.e. when I try with invalid username & password combinations clcik on SignIn, it is waiting for the maximum time and then fails with timeout exception. 
Finally i tried using a `Try / Catch` and verified title but really dont understand why it is not working the negative scenario though the wait condition is login page and I'm using element invisible...

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("valid password");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("invalid password");
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("login")));
    titleActual = driver.getTitle();
    if (titleActual.equals(titleExpected)) {
        System.out.println("Login successful");
    } 
    else {
}
driver.close;
```

Expected: After entering user name and password, once I click on Signin - it should come out of wait and fetch the driver page title
Actual: It is waiting for the maximum time given with error Timeout exception, terminates program execution

Logs:

> Aug 21, 2019 5:38:37 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Detected dialect: W3C Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for element to no longer be visible: By.name: login (tried for
>   60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval) Build info: version:
>   '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System
>   info: host: 'LAPTOP-2PL6I9SD', ip: '192.168.43.30', os.name: 'Windows
>   10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.1'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion:
>   67.0.3, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20190618025334, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.24.0,
>   moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 15188, moz:profile:
>   C:\Users\SWATHI\AppData\Loc..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000,
>   moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true,
>   pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS,
>   platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true,
>   strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad:
>   300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
>   Session ID: e2401e63-ffda-45cd-a73f-ea418e38236d at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
>   at basic_tests.LoginFlightTest.main(LoginFlightTest.java:33)

Comment: It is not working because the element is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will fail because sometimes the network delay could be long and the login button would disappear. However the next page wouldn't be loaded yet. So the positive cases can also fail. You should try to wait for some component on the next page which loads after login.

In negative testcases, you can wait for the appropriate error message which gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified your solution, This could be a problem with your n/w or site it not responding quickly. your script is working properly without any issue.  please try one more time with the below script and don't forget to update the chrome driver path.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Sampletest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\win32\\76.0.3809.68\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("myworld");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("myworld");
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("login")));
    String titleActual = driver.getTitle();
    if (titleActual.equals("titleExpected")) {
        System.out.println("Login successful");
    } else {
    }
    driver.close();
}
}
```

Comment: @Kiran: Are you still facing this issue?